# Помогите связать второй график с данными с bd

Tags: javascript, php, sql, chart.js

Есть два графика, которые отлично работают, когда находятся в разных файлах. Я хочу чтобы они работали в одном файле, а именно, чтобы была кнопка, при нажатии которой первый график менялся на второй график.
как это реализовать? что нужно поменять чтобы всё работало?

Код первого графика находится сверху, а после комментария
//////////////////////////////////////////twochart////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
Я разместил код второго графика.

мой код

```
<?php 
include "database.php";
//запрос в базу 
try{
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;database=$database", $username="root", $password='root');
  $pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e){
  die("Error: Could not able to execute sql.". $e->getMessage());
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Exploring Chart.js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

</head>

<body>

<?php
      try{
        $sql = 
        "select * from forgraf.descriptionlabels
        inner join forgraf.datapoints on descriptionlabels.id = datapoints.desckriptionlabelid";

        $result = $pdo->query($sql);
        if($result->rowCount() > 0){
          ///////////////// передаём данные с базы
          $revenue = array();
          $labelaxis = array();

          //////////////////////////    
          $cost = array();

          // $profit = array();
            ///////////////// передаём данные с базы
          while($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $revenue[] = $row["datapoint"];
            $descriptionlabel = $row["descriptionlabel"];
            $bgcolor = $row["bgcolor"];
            $bordercolor = $row["bordercolor"];
            $labelaxis[] = ucwords($row["labelaxis"]);

            ////////////////////
           $cost[] = $row["cost"];
           

            // $profit[] = $row["profit"];
           }        
          unset($result);
        }
        else {
          echo "No records matching ypur query were found.";
        }
      } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die("Error: Could not able to execute sql.". $e->getMessage());
      }
      unset($pdo);    
      ?>

    <div class="containerbd">

      <div class="container">
          <h1>Привет <?php echo $login; ?></h1>
          <h2>Вы подключились к БД - <?php echo $name_db; ?> </h2>
      </div>
    
      <div class="canvas">
        <canvas id="myChart" ></canvas>
      </div>

      <div class="buttonBox">
        <button onclick="showData(5)">Show 5 Data Points</button>
        <button onclick="showData(7)">Show 7 Data Points</button>
        <button onclick="resetData(0)">Reset</button>
      </div>

    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>

      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

      <script>

      //setup block
      ///////////////// передаём данные с базы
        const revenue = <?php echo json_encode($revenue); ?>;
         const labelaxis = <?php echo json_encode($labelaxis); ?>;
        const descriptionlabel = <?php echo json_encode($descriptionlabel); ?>;
        const bgcolor = <?php echo json_encode($bgcolor); ?>;
        const bordercolor = <?php echo json_encode($bordercolor); ?>;

        //////////////////////////////////////////
        const cost = <?php echo json_encode($cost); ?>;
        console.log(cost);
          

/// data grafika
const data = {
  labels: labelaxis,
  datasets: [{
      label: 'descriptionlabel',
      data: revenue,
      backgroundColor: bgcolor,
      borderColor: bordercolor,
      borderWidth: 1
  }]
};

//config block
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data,
  options: {
      scales: {
          y: {
              beginAtZero: true
          }
      }
  }

};

//render block
const myChart = new Chart(
   document.getElementById('myChart'),
   config
);

//////button function
/////zadaem znachenia dla knopki
function showData(num) {
  const revenueSliced = revenue.slice(0, num);
  const labelaxisSliced = labelaxis.slice(0, num);
  console.log(num);

  myChart.data.datasets[0].data = revenueSliced;
  myChart.data.labels = labelaxisSliced;
  myChart.update();
  
};
/////resetim znachenia dla knopli
function resetData() {
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data = revenue;
  myChart.data.labels = labelaxis;
  myChart.update();
};
</script>


<!-- //////////////////////////////////////////twochart////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->

<?php
      try{
        $sql = 
        "select * from forgraf.descriptionlabelstwo
        inner join forgraf.datapointstwo on descriptionlabelstwo.id = datapointstwo.desckriptionlabelidtwo";

        $result = $pdo->query($sql);
        if($result->rowCount() > 0){
          ///////////////// передаём данные с базы
          $revenuetwo = array();
          $labelaxistwo = array();

          //////////////////////////    
         

          // $profit = array();
            ///////////////// передаём данные с базы
          while($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $revenuetwo[] = $row["datapointtwo"];
            $descriptionlabeltwo = $row["descriptionlabeltwo"];
            $bgcolortwo = $row["bgcolortwo"];
            $bordercolortwo = $row["bordercolortwo"];
            $labelaxistwo[] = ucwords($row["labelaxistwo"]);

            ////////////////////
          
           

            // $profit[] = $row["profit"];
           }        
          unset($result);
        }
        else {
          echo "No records matching ypur query were found.";
        }
      } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die("Error: Could not able to execute sql.". $e->getMessage());
      }
      unset($pdo);    
      ?>

    <div class="containerbd">

      <div class="container">
          <h1>Привет <?php echo $login; ?></h1>
          <h2>Вы подключились к БД - <?php echo $name_db; ?> </h2>
      </div>
    
      <div class="canvas">
        <canvas id="myChart" ></canvas>
      </div>

      <div class="buttonBox">
        <button onclick="showData(5)">Show 5 Data Points</button>
        <button onclick="showData(7)">Show 7 Data Points</button>
        <button onclick="resetData(0)">Reset</button>
      </div>

    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>

      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

      <script>

      //setup block
      ///////////////// передаём данные с базы
        const revenuetwo = <?php echo json_encode($revenuetwo); ?>;
         const labelaxistwo = <?php echo json_encode($labelaxistwo); ?>;
        const descriptionlabeltwo = <?php echo json_encode($descriptionlabeltwo); ?>;
        const bgcolortwo = <?php echo json_encode($bgcolortwo); ?>;
        const bordercolortwo = <?php echo json_encode($bordercolortwo); ?>;

        //////////////////////////////////////////
        
          

/// data grafika
const data = {
  labels: labelaxistwo,
  datasets: [{
      label: 'descriptionlabeltwo',
      data: revenuetwo,
      backgroundColor: bgcolortwo,
      borderColor: bordercolortwo,
      borderWidth: 1
  }]
};

//config block
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data,
  options: {
      scales: {
          y: {
              beginAtZero: true
          }
      }
  }

};
//render block
const myChart = new Chart(
   document.getElementById('myChart'),
   config
);

//////button function

/////zadaem znachenia dla knopki
function showData(num) {
  const revenuetwoSliced = revenuetwo.slice(0, num);
  const labelaxistwoSliced = labelaxistwo.slice(0, num);
  console.log(num);

  myChart.data.datasets[0].data = revenuetwoSliced;
  myChart.data.labels = labelaxistwoSliced;
  myChart.update();
  
};

/////resetim znachenia dla knopli
function resetData() {
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data = revenuetwo;
  myChart.data.labels = labelaxistwo;
  myChart.update();
};


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Уточнил информацию, спасибо

Comment: Какой график вы рисуете? Где эта отрисовка? Ваш кусок кода, читает данные из БД в разные массивы больше ничего не происходит.

Comment: @KordDEM, прикрепил остальную часть кода

Comment: Оформите пожалуйста адекватно. Просто приведите весь код и опишите проблему(не в тегах кода). Не надо по 3 раза дублировать один фрагмент.

Comment: @KordDEM, прошу прошения, я новичок и плохо разбираюсь. Так лучше? Что ещё нужно добавить?

Comment: У вас много const переменных(data, config, myChart), которые вы используете как в данных для первого графика так и для второго. Если вы в одну переменную const data присвоите какие-то значения в дальнейшем она не изменится как не изменяйте. Так же много элементов с одинаковыми идентификаторами и проч. Вы в первом случае пишите в элемент myChart и у вас второй элемент есть с таких же id.

Comment: @KordDEM
 То есть мне нужно изменить названия переменных data, config и myChart? и тогда будет работать? Можете прикрепить код с изменением переменных в ответе, если вам не сложно =)

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код напоминает какую-то свалку всего на свете и бездумно продублирован. По хорошему все это нужно писать с 0. Попробовал разобраться, но за работоспособность не ручаюсь. Так же вы бездумно используете оператор const. Если вы в дальнейшем как-то собираетесь изменять переменную, то используйте стандартный let.

```
<?php 
include "database.php";
//запрос в базу 
try{
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;database=$database", $username="root", $password='root');
  $pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e){
  die("Error: Could not able to execute sql.". $e->getMessage());
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Exploring Chart.js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

</head>

<body>

<?php
      try{
        $sql = 
        "select * from forgraf.descriptionlabels
        inner join forgraf.datapoints on descriptionlabels.id = datapoints.desckriptionlabelid";

        $result = $pdo->query($sql);
        if($result->rowCount() > 0){
          ///////////////// передаём данные с базы
          $revenue = array();
          $labelaxis = array();

          //////////////////////////    
          $cost = array();

          // $profit = array();
            ///////////////// передаём данные с базы
          while($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $revenue[] = $row["datapoint"];
            $descriptionlabel = $row["descriptionlabel"];
            $bgcolor = $row["bgcolor"];
            $bordercolor = $row["bordercolor"];
            $labelaxis[] = ucwords($row["labelaxis"]);

            ////////////////////
           $cost[] = $row["cost"];
           

            // $profit[] = $row["profit"];
           }        
          unset($result);
        }
        else {
          echo "No records matching ypur query were found.";
        }
      } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die("Error: Could not able to execute sql.". $e->getMessage());
      }
    try{
        $sql = 
        "select * from forgraf.descriptionlabelstwo
        inner join forgraf.datapointstwo on descriptionlabelstwo.id = datapointstwo.desckriptionlabelidtwo";

        $result = $pdo->query($sql);
        if($result->rowCount() > 0){
          ///////////////// передаём данные с базы
          $revenuetwo = array();
          $labelaxistwo = array();

          //////////////////////////    
         

          // $profit = array();
            ///////////////// передаём данные с базы
          while($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $revenuetwo[] = $row["datapointtwo"];
            $descriptionlabeltwo = $row["descriptionlabeltwo"];
            $bgcolortwo = $row["bgcolortwo"];
            $bordercolortwo = $row["bordercolortwo"];
            $labelaxistwo[] = ucwords($row["labelaxistwo"]);

            ////////////////////
          
           

            // $profit[] = $row["profit"];
           }        
          unset($result);
        }
        else {
          echo "No records matching ypur query were found.";
        }
      } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die("Error: Could not able to execute sql.". $e->getMessage());
      }
      unset($pdo);
      ?>

    <div class="containerbd">

      <div class="container">
          <h1>Привет <?php echo $login; ?></h1>
          <h2>Вы подключились к БД - <?php echo $name_db; ?> </h2>
      </div>
    
      <div class="canvas">
        <canvas id="myChart" ></canvas>
      </div>

      <div class="buttonBox">
        <button onclick="showData(5,0)">Show 5 Data Points</button>
        <button onclick="showData(7,0)">Show 7 Data Points</button>
        <button onclick="resetData(0,0)">Reset</button>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="containerbd">

      <div class="container">
          <h1>Привет <?php echo $login; ?></h1>
          <h2>Вы подключились к БД - <?php echo $name_db; ?> </h2>
      </div>
    
      <div class="canvas">
        <canvas id="myCharttwo" ></canvas>
      </div>

      <div class="buttonBox">
        <button onclick="showData(5,1)">Show 5 Data Points</button>
        <button onclick="showData(7,1)">Show 7 Data Points</button>
        <button onclick="resetData(0,1)">Reset</button>
      </div>

    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>

      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

      <script>

        //setup block
        ///////////////// передаём данные с базы
        const revenue = <?php echo json_encode($revenue); ?>;
         const labelaxis = <?php echo json_encode($labelaxis); ?>;
        const descriptionlabel = <?php echo json_encode($descriptionlabel); ?>;
        const bgcolor = <?php echo json_encode($bgcolor); ?>;
        const bordercolor = <?php echo json_encode($bordercolor); ?>;

        //////////////////////////////////////////
        const cost = <?php echo json_encode($cost); ?>;
        console.log(cost);
        
        //setup block
        ///////////////// передаём данные с базы
        const revenuetwo = <?php echo json_encode($revenuetwo); ?>;
        const labelaxistwo = <?php echo json_encode($labelaxistwo); ?>;
        const descriptionlabeltwo = <?php echo json_encode($descriptionlabeltwo); ?>;
        const bgcolortwo = <?php echo json_encode($bgcolortwo); ?>;
        const bordercolortwo = <?php echo json_encode($bordercolortwo); ?>;

        //////////////////////////////////////////
          

/// data grafika
const data = {
  labels: labelaxis,
  datasets: [{
      label: 'descriptionlabel',
      data: revenue,
      backgroundColor: bgcolor,
      borderColor: bordercolor,
      borderWidth: 1
  }]
};

const datatwo = {
  labels: labelaxistwo,
  datasets: [{
      label: 'descriptionlabeltwo',
      data: revenuetwo,
      backgroundColor: bgcolortwo,
      borderColor: bordercolortwo,
      borderWidth: 1
  }]

//config block
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data,
  options: {
      scales: {
          y: {
              beginAtZero: true
          }
      }
  }
};

//config block
const configtwo = {
  type: 'bar',
  datatwo,
  options: {
      scales: {
          y: {
              beginAtZero: true
          }
      }
  }
};

//render block
const myChart = new Chart(
   document.getElementById('myChart'),
   config
);

//render block
const myCharttwo = new Chart(
   document.getElementById('myCharttwo'),
   configtwo
);

//////button function
/////zadaem znachenia dla knopki
function showData(num, param) {
if (param){
    revenuetwoSliced = revenuetwo.slice(0, num);
    labelaxistwoSliced = labelaxistwo.slice(0, num);
    console.log(num);

    myCharttwo.data.datasets[0].datatwo = revenuetwoSliced;
    myCharttwo.data.labels = labelaxistwoSliced;
    myCharttwo.update();
}else{
    revenueSliced = revenue.slice(0, num);
    labelaxisSliced = labelaxis.slice(0, num);
    console.log(num);

    myChart.data.datasets[0].data = revenueSliced;
    myChart.data.labels = labelaxisSliced;
    myChart.update();
}

  
};
/////resetim znachenia dla knopli
function resetData(param) {
    if (param){
        myCharttwo.data.datasets[0].datatwo = revenuetwo;
        myCharttwo.data.labels = labelaxistwo;
        myCharttwo.update();
    }else{
        myChart.data.datasets[0].data = revenue;
        myChart.data.labels = labelaxis;
        myChart.update();
    }
};
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо за предоставленный ответ. Но графики не отображаются(

Comment: Отлаживайте, закоменчивайте лишние куски кода и потихоньку раскоменчивая, смотрите где у вас возникают ошибки. Не думаю, что кто-то будет смотреть вашу портянку)